# Remove particular similar element from the list in python

Tags: python

I am having the list like below

```
list1=['abc','oops','#exclude=10','exclude=java* kln*','smith','johns']
```

I am trying to delete the element which contains the word 'exclude' by using the below code.

```
x=0  

for i in list1:

    if 'exclude' in i:
        list1.pop(x)
    x+=1 

print list1
```

When I run the program, it is removing the first `exclude` not the second one. Please let me know how to remove all `exclude` and what is the mistake I am doing?

Comment: Instead of deleting elements like this, Better will be to create a new list with the strings that do not contain 'exclude'.

Comment: use new_list = [x for x in list1 if 'exclude' not in x]

Comment: `pop` always removes the last element in the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since while deleting first element list shifting it's element that's why this is happening.

**You can try this:-**

```
list1=['abc','oops','#exclude=10','exclude=java* kln*','smith','johns']
new_ls = [list1.index(x) for x in list1 if 'exclude' in x]
for i in reversed(new_ls):
    list1.pop(i)
print(list1)
```

Comment: Nice its working. Please give me the normal code instead of using list comprehension

Comment: @iamarunk  it's nothing but iterating through list for filtration u have to go through list only either you can choose for loop or enumeration but you have to go through list...alright.

Comment: thank you so much its fixed my problem :)

Comment: @iamarunk  ..ur welcome you can upvote it as well.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple solution:

```
import re
list1=['abc','oops','#exclude=10','exclude=java* kln*','smith','johns']
regex = re.compile('.*exclude.*')
okay_items = [x for x in list1 if not regex.match(x)]
print(okay_items)
```

In your solution, you have used pop() and as per the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html),

> list.pop([i]):
>
> Remove the item at the given position in the list, and return it. If
> no index is specified, a.pop() removes and returns the last item in
> the list.

Answer (score 1):

The reason you are experiencing this kind of behavior is that you are mutating `list1` as you are iterating over it. At the point when you pop `#exclude=10`
from `list1`, `x == 2` and once the element is popped

```
     list1 == ['abc','oops','exclude=java* kln*','smith','johns']
```

Now `x` increments to `3`, but `list1[3]==smith` after popping, whereas you were expecting it to be `exclude=java* kln*` as in your original version of `list1`.

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
>>> list1=['abc','oops','#exclude=10','exclude=java* kln*','smith','johns']
>>> [i for i in list1 if 'exclude' not in  i]
['abc', 'oops', 'smith', 'johns']
>>>
```

simple method without list comprehension and effect in original list,

```
>>> list1=['abc','oops','#exclude=10','exclude=java* kln*','smith','johns']
>>> for i in filter(lambda x: 'exclude' in x, list1):
...   list1.remove(i)
... 
>>> list1
['abc', 'oops', 'smith', 'johns']
>>>
```

Comment: @Mohammed thanks for your reply.   How to write normal code instead of list comprehension. Also how to effect that in the original list

Comment: `>>> list1=['abc','oops','#exclude=10','exclude=java* kln*','smith','johns']
>>> for i in range(len(list1)):
...   if 'exclude' in list1[i]:
...     print i
...     list1.pop(i)
... 
2
'#exclude=10'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
IndexError: list index out of range
>>> `

Comment: but you wont do it in original list.. once loop it took initial length of list.. during loop if your  value match you have to pop. so it affect len of list . on next loop it affect further

Comment: my answer has been updated as you want... check and let me know

Answer (score 0):

The method `pop()` removes and returns last object or obj from the list.

Instead you can create a new list which does not include strings with `"exclude"` like this.

```
list1=['abc','oops','#exclude=10','exclude=java* kln*','smith','johns']
listWithoutExclude = []
for each in list1:
    if "exclude" not in each:
        listWithoutExclude.append(each)
print listWithoutExclude
```